# Violin produces empty plot when only two values in the series and scale count used

Tags: r, ggplot2

My violin plot produces an empty plot when there are only two values in the series and scale count used.

```
library(ggplot2)
d1 <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"),y=c(1,2,2,1,2,1)) # Two series of three with different values through each series
d2 <- data.frame(x=c("a","a","a","b","b"),    y=c(1,2,2,1,2))   # Two series, one of three, one of two with different values through each series
ggplot(data=d1) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y))                     # This works
ggplot(data=d1) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y), scale="count")      # This works
ggplot(data=d2) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y))                     # This works
ggplot(data=d2) + geom_violin(aes(x=x,y=y), scale="count")      # This produces an empty plot
```

The first three work fine. The fourth one produces an empty plot. Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?
Thanks

Comment: Just confirming that this is a bug in v1.0.1 and has been fixed in the development version according to Hadley.